# react native flexbox row and cloumn

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flexbox

Good Day! I am working on a design task to develop myself in reactnative flex concepts. I am trying to achieve the below design

[image: I want to create a design like below image. But I cannot able to bring the Date column below Item ID. I have tried(justifycontent:"spacebetween", flexWrap:"wrap", flexdirection:"start and stop")]Anyone can guide me how to get the above output. I have one **container** which is "**FlexDirection:Row**" and ItemID, ItemName and Date in one container where I am using "**FlexDirection:"Column**". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you

```
const App = () => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item ID</Text>
            <TextInput />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Item Name</Text>
            <TextInput />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text>Date</Text>
            <TextInput />
        </View>
    </View>
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    item: {
        width: '50%'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have tried this, but I am using DropdownBox for Item ID and  TextInput for Item Name and date time picker for Date at that time the lines are getting collapsed.

Comment: Did you try to set a special height to all item? like this => item: { width: '50%,    height: 200 }

Comment: There are three columns in the section, first one is the picture above I have asked and for that only I want to fix the height and width . For remaining two columns there are two fields where I don't want to give size and  split in to two columns.